# RxJS - observable doesn't complete when an error occurs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

When I create an observable from scratch, and have the observer error, then complete, the done part of the subscription never is invoked.

```
var observer = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
    observer.onError(new Error('no!'));
    observer.onCompleted();
})

observer.subscribe(
    function(x) { console.log('succeeded with ' + x ) },
    function(x) { console.log('errored with ' + x ) },
    function() { console.log('completed') }
)
```

The output is:

```
errored with Error: no!
```

I'd expect it to be:

```
errored with Error: no!
completed
```

If I change the code to invoke onNext instead of onError, the observable properly completes:

```
var observer = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
    observer.onNext('Hi!');
    observer.onCompleted();
})

observer.subscribe(
    function(x) { console.log('succeeded with ' + x ) },
    function(x) { console.log('errored with ' + x ) },
    function() { console.log('completed') }
)
```

I get the expected output:

```
succeeded with Hi! 
completed
```

Why does it not complete when an error has occured?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

That's because an error means completion, so the callback associated to `onCompleted` never gets called. You can review here Rxjs contract for observables (http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) :

> An Observable may make zero or more OnNext notifications, each representing a single emitted item, and it may then follow those emission notifications by either an OnCompleted or an OnError notification, but not both. Upon issuing an OnCompleted or OnError notification, it may not thereafter issue any further notifications.`

For error management, you can have a look at :
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/errors.md

Answer (score 50):

Another and probably the simplest solution might be using the `add()` function.
The statement will be always executed regardless an error
occured or not (like the `finally` statement in most programming languages).

```
observer.subscribe(
    function(x) { console.log('succeeded with ' + x ) },
    function(x) { console.log('errored with ' + x ) },
    function() { console.log('completed') }
)
.add(() => {
    console.log("Will be executed on both success or error of the previous subscription")
);
```

Comment: Like a charm, when finally() does´t works with an error

Answer (score 28):

While I was having the same question, I bumped into this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7865).

Apparently `finally` method of `Observable` object needs to be used in this case.

Quoting from Aleksandr-Leotech from that thread:

> Complete and finally are totally different things. Complete means that
>   the observable steam was finished successfully. Because you can have
>   many success calls. Finally means that steam has ended, either
>   successfully or not.
>
> It is not obvious with HTTP requests, but imagine two additional
>   scenarios.
>
> 1. Mouse events. You will be receiving a never-ending steam of success
>      callbacks, but you will never receive finally or complete, because
>      user events will never stop (unless you trigger an exception with
>      buggy code, then you will get error and finally).
> 2. Working with web sockets. You will get multiple success callbacks, but at some point in time your communication with back end will stop and you will get both complete and finally unless you have some errors, which will call error and finally.
>
> So, you might be getting multiple or no success calls, zero or one error call, zero or one complete and zero or one finally.

Comment: "Complete and finally are totally different things" - Yeh, I saw the same github issue just now. Except the words in english are practically synonyms for one another so people assume they mean the same in other contexts (if anything, generally 'finally' is the last thing you do before something is 'complete'). A fair few rxjs questions could have been avoided by naming things right :-(

Answer (score 26):

To run a callback when observable completes or errors, you should use `finalize`.

Ex:

```
this.service.yourObservable
            .pipe(
               finalize(() => {
                 // * This will always run when observable finishes the stream
                 console.log("Finally!");
                 // * callback for finally
                })  
             ).subscribe(
              {
               next: () => { // * Callback for success },
               error: () => { // * Callback for error },
               complete: () => {// * This gets called only on success }
              })
```

Comment: What is the point of `complete` if it only fires on success?

Comment: I guess it's that you don't have to use a pipe when it successfully finishes, the code you write most likely will finish successfully then fail, so this should be the reason I guess

Comment: @RichardBarraclough "next" can be fired several times and carries data, "complete" explicitly tells you, nothing will be fired anymore (and has no data), "error" means, something went wrong, and provides the information on what went wrong. There is no automatic recovery, an error means I'm dead and here is why, it's up to you to use a retry operator.