# Confusion in Angular 2 Http Post Request

Tags: php, angular

First of all. Please bear with my questions.

What I am doing is just performing an ajax request which will return a response data of string.

Here's my php

```
<?php
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

     echo 'Peenoise Crazy';
?>
```

Http request

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post('./app/parsers/peenoise.php', '', options)
    .then(val => console.log(val))
```

This doesn't work. But if I change the url into this `http://localhost:8912/app/parsers/peenoise.php`. It works.

Questions

1. Why `./app/parsers/peenoise.php` doesn't work?
2. If I change the url to `http://localhost:8912/app/parsers/peenoise.php`. Why do I need to put `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')`? It is on the same folder of my app.
3. How to use http.post without passing an url of `http://localhost:8912/route/to/phpfolder.php`?

Any help would be appreciated. Please guide me to this. Thanks

Comment: quando o usuário faz uma solicitação usando ajax angular 2, o pedido é de navegador do cliente. O pedido não vem de servidor para servidor. Por isso, é necessário utilizar o caminho do servidor. lembre-se que no momento em que o aplicativo está no navegador do cliente.

not is possible to make a request to the server that way you want.

Comment: Have you tried `/app/parsers/peenoise.php` (without the leading dot)? It seems like you're trying to use directory path notation, but a dot is not interpreted the same way when it comes to URLs.

Comment: @user3608792 yes. I tried everything and doesn't have an error on console and doesn't work.

Comment: Instead  of `.then()` you could try using the `.map().subscribe()` pattern.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671715/angular2-http-get-map-subscribe-and-observable-pattern-basic-understan

Answer (score 0):

Post requires a full or a relative URL to work. You can use:

```
this.http.post('/parsers/peenoise.php', '', options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Angular looks for a backend server to post the data, so Imagine in your post request is like below

```
this.http.post('./app/parsers/peenoise.php', '', options).then(val => console.log(val))
```

It will try to make the post request at the location 
imagine you are serving angular on localhost:4200

```
http://localhost:4200/app/parsers/peenoise.php
```

Now to answer your Questions :

1)`./app/parsers/peenoise.php` doesn't work because it's actually trying to find it from your backend service

2)You need to put `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')` whenever you are making an http request to a different server than from the one which your site is currently using, if you don't use that you'll end up with `Connection_refused_Error`.

3)If you want to use just angular then there are mockAckends, [in-memory-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-in-memory-web-api)

An example using mockBackEnd is 
[here](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular2-registration-login-example)