# Observable: Why result not in subscribe() success function if preceded by map()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671715/angular2-http-get-map-subscribe-and-observable-pattern-basic-understan/34672550) which was really helpful to understand Observables, but there is still something I don't get.

In the plunker it [refers to](http://plnkr.co/edit/oYFhsMEJFMi7NzGPpvT1?p=preview), I changed the "src/myfreinds.ts" to see a bit what happen and added some console log:

First I left it as the same:

```
  export class FriendsList{

    result:Array<Object>; 
    constructor(http: Http) { 
      console.log("Friends are being called");
      http.get('friends.json')
        .map(response => {
            console.log("map");
            console.info(response);
            response.json(); //MISTAKE WAS HERE SHOULD HAVE HAD "return response.json()" INSTEAD AS EXPLAINED IN THE ANSWER GIVEN
          })
        .subscribe(result => {
          console.log("subscribe");
          console.info(result);
          this.result =result;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

In that case I can see in the log that `result` beneath `subscribe` is `undefined`. But `response` beneath `map` contains the response indeed.

If I take away the `map` part and keep the `subscribe` part like this:

```
export class FriendsList{

  result:Array<Object>; 
  constructor(http: Http) { 
    console.log("Friends are being called");
    http.get('friends.json')
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          console.log("subscribe");
          console.info(result);
          this.result =result;
        }
      );
   }
}
```

This time, in the console I can see beneath subscribe the details of the `result` and not `undefined` like I had in previous case.

**I'd like to understand why subscribe, success function does not contain everytime the result whether `map` function is applied or not?**

Comment: "`result` beneath subscribe is `undefined`" it is not? http://plnkr.co/edit/EOkO81iMWQzeLcRiuZbr?p=preview

Comment: I understand my mistake, at first, I had written `.map(response =>{console.log("map");console.info(response);response.json()})` instead of `.map(response =>{console.log("map");console.info(response);**return** response.json()})` Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subscribe()` gets passed as `result` what the previous operator `.map()` returns - `return response.json()`.

It is quite possible that `response != undefined` but `response.json() == null`