# implementation of post web service in ionic 2 using angular2

Tags: web-services, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to implement post webservice in angular2. 
I have tried to hit the URL through postman and its working. But when i'm trying to implement it in angular, I'm not getting any response.
The following is my code sample:

```
 load(username, password) {

        console.log(username,"  ", password);
        let postData = {"username":username, "password" : password, 
                "userdeviceInfo": [{
                "deviceId": "APA91bGUZuKVbqur7Qq2gy2eyomWgXkIU5Jcmmtmgl4IGuzVzwiJVMZgAHj3Bx6yrnW0oEZlEtB9XdcR6AOpKyEMVSWwQ_UIfNX6T0iwq28hnufOhauVdTYZQSWWPAdDrdg58cjnL5T-",
                "platform":"Android"
                          }]};

        //let body= JSON.stringify(postData); 

      //console.log("body---"+body)

        this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

            this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
                method: RequestMethod.Post,
                url: this.url,
                headers: this.headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(postData)
            })

    console.log("body---"+this.requestoptions)

    return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    if (res) {

                      console.log(res.json());
                        return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }];
                    }})
               .subscribe(res => this.data = res);
```

the error i'm recieving is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "MY_URL". Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500
```

I'm kind of stuck here. Can anyone help me find where am i going wrong?

Comment: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500` this is likely a cors issue

Comment: i handled the cors issue by disabling it

Comment: my get service is running fine

Comment: well the error is preflight so before actual request and code 500 has to do with server error..maybe check server side log?

Comment: server logs doesn't show anything. Can u tell me what does subscribe do

Comment: subscribe is a method to call an observable and receive its response.. check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/34672550/4826457

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the problem here.

Comment: is there anything wrong in the code above because when i tried my web service on postman, it works. but through my code it shows error

Comment: I don think there is an issue.. but generally you use `this.http.post(url,body,requestoptions)` instead of `this.http.request` directly. Also cannot know what headers your server is expecting..

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755350/using-http-rest-apis-with-angular-2/34758630#34758630)  is the link i refered

Comment: also tried this.http.post(url, body, requestoptions) earlier....same error there too

Answer (score 0):

here is a POST example:

```
rate(url: string, body: { value: number}) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post(url, body, options).toPromise().then(
          response => response.json(),
          err => err
  );
}
```

Of course you can delete `toPromise()` to use observables, this is for an example app :)

hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to make a http post :

```
let headers = new Headers();
let body = {"username":username, "password" : password, 
                "userdeviceInfo": [{
                "deviceId": "APA91bGUZuKVbqur7Qq2gy2eyomWgXkIU5Jcmmtmgl4IGuzVzwiJVMZgAHj3Bx6yrnW0oEZlEtB9XdcR6AOpKyEMVSWwQ_UIfNX6T0iwq28hnufOhauVdTYZQSWWPAdDrdg58cjnL5T-",
                "platform":"Android"
                          }]};

headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post("theurl", '', {
    body : JSON.stringify(body),
    headers : headers
})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data=>{

},
err=>{

},
()=>{

})
```

Comment: giving the same error. it has something to do with 'cors', i checked...can you help with 'CORS'

Comment: If it is a CORS issue then install the CORS extension on your chrome browser and enable CORS, it will work. Or if you want it to be handled in the mobile app, the plugin cordova-whitelist should be installed which handles CORS. By default, the latest versions of ionic will include this plugin in the config.xml and build the app along with it..

Comment: Also console.log and check the value of this.url before making POST request.. It is throwing a 500 error which means internal server error..

Comment: -XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.16.4.232:8080/GNE_CONF/mobile/doLogin_mobile. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500 and XHR failed loading: POST "http://172.16.4.232:8080/GNE_CONF/mobile/doLogin_mobile".- This is my complete error

Comment: i have added CORS extension already and also plugin is present, but still it throws this error. i have seen videos over youtube for http post request...still it got me no where

Comment: Did you install the chrome extension "CORS" ? also, curious to know which backend you are using..

Comment: What back-end are you using for your api?

Comment: [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) is the extension I've added and I'm using apache tomcat server.

Comment: This is a great tool to have to test your rest api's. Try simulating the POST request using this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: looks like my server doesn't have CORS enabled

Comment: which language have you written your server in php,java,..??

Comment: it is written in java