# Ionic 2 HTTP Provider returning undefined the first time, but the correct data the second time

Tags: angular, http, ionic2

I have created an Ionic 2 provider that gets sends login information to the server and then returns the data correctly. The problem is, that on the first click of the button that activates the provider and sends everything to the server, the first return is `undefined`, while the second click returns the correct data.

Provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the HttpProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class HttpProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello HttpProvider Provider');
  }

  get() {

  }

  post() {

  }

  login(username, password, url) {
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http.post(url,
      {"username": username,
      "password": password,
    }, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

TS File of the Page with the Button:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { HttpProvider } from '../../providers/http-provider'

/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login-page',
  templateUrl: 'login-page.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  username:any;
  password:any;
  stuff:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: HttpProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  login() {
    this.http.login(this.username, this.password, WORKING_IP_ADDRESS).subscribe(stuff => this.stuff = JSON.stringify(stuff));

    console.log(this.stuff)
  }
}
```

Some example input and output would be:

```
input:
  username: bob
  password: bob

output on first click:
  undefined

output on second click where the login is successful:
 {"id":"t326t34ergfsdy5u54terg324t37u567uygt5243y756u467u756y","ttl":54325432,"created":"2017-05-10T02:19:05.423Z","userId":63546543}
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with it?

Comment: You might be mssing a provider
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login-page',
  providers: [HttpProvider]
  templateUrl: 'login-page.html',
})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On you Login Page the **stuff** variable is undefined because its declared as any and your async operation is not complete yet.

```
login() {
   this.http.login(this.username,this.password,WORKING_IP_ADDRESS)
   .subscribe((stuff) => {
      //Async operation complete
      this.stuff = JSON.stringify(stuff);

      //this is the correct result from async operation
      console.log("complete",this.stuff);

      //do your stuff with this.stuff variable here

   });

   // on the firstime button clicked Async operation is not complete yet 
   so the code outside callback will log undefined
   // the second time its fired the code below will log the first async result
   console.log("not complete", this.stuff);
}
```

if you're looking for another async operation after login considering using Observable **SwitchMap** to switch the operation to another observable and then subscribe, so your this.stuff variable can be used by another async operation.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! It seems kind of janky that I need to do console.log in order to make it work though and have it be async. Is there a way I could declare the `stuff` variable to have it automatically wait for the correct response?

Comment: (stuff) variable inside Observable Subscribe or Observable SwitchMap callback will always wait and return the correct data from async operation if the operation success, sometimes it can fail too so you need to handle the error.

Angular use RxJs Observable to simplify Async operation and make an Asynchronous Operation Sequence. if you want to wait the result before executing any code make sure to place it inside the callback. code outside it will not wait the async operation complete.