# Passing json data from http service to component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have separate **requests.service.ts** and **schedule.ts**.
I am unable to pass the json returned from method from **requests.service.ts**, even though I mapped it when I returned it.

My code for **request.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from "@angular/http";
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor(public http: Http) { }    
        requestMethod() {     
           return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json())
        }
}
```

My code for **schedule.ts**

```
let data = this.loginService.requestMethod();
```

Where `data` returns `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}...`

Comment: try use subscribe() method

Comment: also write this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671715/angular2-http-get-map-subscribe-and-observable-pattern-basic-understan/34672550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is observable, no plain data. You need to subscribe it and handle it. For example:

```
let data;
this.loginService.requestMethod()
     .subscribe(okData => data = okData); // or this.data = okData if it's a class' field.
```

You can also handle what should be done if request has failed. [You can refer to this documentation to learn more about subscription](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md)