# Angular then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

#### TYPESCRIPT CODE:

```
helloworld(){
    this.get_data().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}

get_data(){
    return this.http.get('assets/data/user.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        return this.json_data = data;
    });
}
```

Anyone can please tell me why then is not working. How can I resolve this? Sorry for my weak English.

Comment: You are doing .then on .sbscribe, that's why. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34671715/5468463

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 http.get() ,map(), subscribe() and observable pattern - basic understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671715/angular2-http-get-map-subscribe-and-observable-pattern-basic-understan)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do **then** on a **subscribe**. You have an **observable** which generates a stream of data, this means that you can't actually know when the stream will end.

In the other hand **then** is used with **promises**. A **promise** has only **ONE** data to return. Once the data arrive the **then** activates.

In your case this what you need to do:

```
helloworld(){
    this.get_data().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
}

get_data(){
    return this.http.get('assets/data/user.json').map(res => res.json());
}
```