# why observable pipe is not working in component?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, observable

I have an observable which is maked with firebase/fireStore. if I subscribe this observable in component it works . but If I pipe this observable it doesn't work even though i expect . and I am not getting any error. my question; why it doesn't work?

my codes;

service;

```
getLastSeans(uid) {
    return this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${uid}/lastseans/seansLive`).valueChanges();
  }
```

component;

with pipe it doesn't work

```
this.roomService.getLastSeans(this.userId).pipe(map(x=>{console.log(x);return x;}));
```

if I subscribe it work like this;

```
this.roomService.getLastSeans(this.userId).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

**I want to learn why this happen?**

Comment: Observable start running pipe methods only when you subscribe its.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 http.get() ,map(), subscribe() and observable pattern - basic understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671715/angular2-http-get-map-subscribe-and-observable-pattern-basic-understan)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding a pipe does not force the observable to be evaluated, it creates the new observable instance with extra logic defined in pipes, according to [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators):

> A Pipeable Operator is a function that takes an Observable as its
>   input and returns another Observable

To evaluate the new observable, you have to `subscribe` to it, e.g. using the `.subscribe` call:

```
this.roomService.getLastSeans(this.userId)
    .pipe(map(x=>{
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    })).subscribe();
```

Please note, that empty `.subscribe` is acceptable here, as the logic is defined in the pipes.

Or, altering the template to use the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), e.g:

```
<app-live-sean *ngFor="let item of liveSeans | async"></app-live-sean>
```

Assuming that `liveSeans` is the field of the component, which sets as

```
this.liveSeans = this.roomService.getLastSeans(this.userId)
    .pipe(map(x=>{
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    }));
```

In this case `AsyncPipe` will subscribe to it, receive the results and unsubscribe from the observable, keeping the memory safe without leaks.

Comment: thanks for answer. the basic point is here"Adding a pipe does not force the observable to be evaluated, it creates the new observable instance with extra logic defined in pipes, according to"