# How refresh http service after error in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this service that is an http get request that response with a list of products:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

  @Injectable()
    export class ProductService{
      constructor(private _http:Http) {}

      getData() {

          return this._http.get(`URL GOES HERE`)
            .map(res => res.json());

      }
    }
```

and this component call the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
 class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public _productService: ProductService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this._productService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => this.products = data,
               err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

I want to manage the .error;  when the service goes in error, i want to refresh the service:

```
this._productService.getData()
          .subscribe(data => this.products = data,
                   err => { **recall this._productService.getData()** }
```

Thank for all responses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJS - observable doesn't complete when an error occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783967/rxjs-observable-doesnt-complete-when-an-error-occurs)

Answer (score 2):

you can use retry operator from rxjs/operators, just specify how many times you want to retry as an argument retry(x_times):

```
...
ngOnInit() {
    this._productService.getData().pipe(retry(1))
      .subscribe(data => this.products = data,
               err => console.log(err));
  }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **retryWhen** operator instead of retry to avoid rapid succession of http calls, and you can retry the call just in case of **503 error** **(Service Unavailable)**

```
.pipe( retryWhen(error => {
       return error.pipe(
        flatMap((error: any) => {
             if(error.status  === 503) {
               return Observable.of(error.status).delay(1000)
             }
             return Observable.throw({error: ''});
          }),
          take(3) // controls number of retries
      )                
});
```